# Resize UITableView Height (embedded inside UIScrollView)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, autolayout

In my `storyboard` I am using `AutoLayout` and my `UITableView` is embedded inside `UIScrollView`. The number of cells of the `UITableView` changes during runtime and I want to dynamically change the height of the frame of my `UITableView` and also disable scrolling in `UITableView`.
The code that I got shows the `UITableView` but I could not resize the height.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource ,UITableViewDelegate  {
@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
var array: [CellData] = [CellData]()
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : CellKistNames = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! CellKistNames
    cell.cellSiingle.text = "cellData"
    return cell
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.array.count
}
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension

}
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    myTableView.reloadData()
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.myTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
    self.myTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    self.myTableView.dataSource = self
    self.myTableView.delegate = self

    array = [
            CellData(name: "one"),CellData(name: "two"),CellData(name: "three"),CellData(name: "four"),CellData(name: "five"),CellData(name: "six"),CellData(name: "sevens")
            ]
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever collection which is using to render table view get changed, update UITableView **height constrain** also with new height as [collection Count]*tableViewHeight.

In XIB there are two properties for horizontal and vertical scrolling of table view, just uncheck both of them to disable scrolling in UITableView.

Comment: @ Mrs. Agarwal....Thank you for the reply..The scroll got disabled but how should i update UiTableView height

Comment: You have to create a property for height constraint, like @property (nonatomic, strong) NSLayoutConstraint *tableViewHeightConstraint;     Now add this constraint to table view, like [self.tableView addConstraint:self.tableViewHeightConstraint];                                                You can update this constraint value like,self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = 3*50;(suppose 30 as collection count and 50 as table view cell's height).                                     After updating constraint value call "updateConstraints" on table view, like, [self.tableView updateConstraints];